# macOS High Sierra: find Oracle Instant client installation and its version

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, instantclient

How can I find Oracle Instant Client installation on macOS High Sierra and check its version ?
All the search gave nothing.
Nevertheless, when I run `sqlplus` in the Terminal, it displays the following:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Wed Jul 11 20:48:22 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name:
```

When checking where `sqlplus`, I get the following:

```
~ type sqlplus
sqlplus is /usr/local/bin/sqlplus
```

Any idea ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You know the version now, it's 12.1.0.2.0 - as reported by SQL*Plus running out of whatever HOME it's installed in.

If on Windows - check your PATH.

It sounds like an [Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html) *install*, which isn't really installed, just extracted from an archive.

Say on Windows, my path includes:

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\instantclient_12_1;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox;C:\Users\jdsmith\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin
```

Whichever Oracle looking thing shows FIRST, is likely to be what you're running.

But on OS X, per the instructions:

> 3. Add links to $HOME/lib or /usr/local/lib to enable applications to find the libraries. For example, OCI based applications could do:
>
>    mkdir ~/lib   ln -s ~/instantclient_12_2/libclntsh.dylib ~/lib/   ln
>      -s ~/instantclient_12_2/libclntsh.dylib.12.1 ~/lib/

Go check the links. Assuming you followed the directions when you installed this, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I've just find the answer:

- run `locate sqlplus`
- you should get all the paths to instant client:

  /Users/Serguei/soft/instantclient-sqlplus-macos.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip
  /usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-sqlplus
  /usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-sqlplus/12.1.0.2.0
  /usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-sqlplus/12.1.0.2.0/.brew
  /usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-sqlplus/12.1.0.2.0/.brew/instantclient-sqlplus.rb
  /usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-sqlplus/12.1.0.2.0/INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
  /usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-sqlplus/12.1.0.2.0/bin
  /usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-sqlplus/12.1.0.2.0/bin/sqlplus
  /usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-sqlplus/12.1.0.2.0/lib
  /usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-sqlplus/12.1.0.2.0/lib/libsqlplus.dylib
  /usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-sqlplus/12.1.0.2.0/lib/libsqlplusic.dylib
  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/instantclienttap/homebrew-instantclient/Formula/instantclient-sqlplus.rb
  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/instantclienttap/homebrew-instantclient/Formula/instantclient-sqlplus11.rb
  /usr/local/bin/sqlplus
  /usr/local/lib/libsqlplus.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libsqlplusic.dylib
  /usr/local/opt/instantclient-sqlplus
  /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked/instantclient-sqlplus
  /usr/local/var/homebrew/locks/instantclient-sqlplus.formula.lock

Hope this helps.